# Failed to insert data into remote server DB from java windows application

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am working on java windows application. I connected my application to remote database server and inserted data. But when I executed my application, it is displaying the message **Duplicate entry 0 for key PRIMARY**. I tried to solve this issue but still it is displaying the same. Also I am using 10 to 15 tables to insert the data. In the output, the error message(Duplicate entry 0 for key PRIMARY) is coming but it is not mentioning the table name.

Can anybody please help me in this regard?

Thank you

Comment: Identify the offending query and write it here.

Comment: Could whoever thought this was a *good* question explain to me their reasoning?

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when a null value has been inserted (or has tried to be inserted) into the table as a primary key. If you have access to the displays through mysql manager or something, see if there are rows inserted with null values.